# how to update one component if there is changes in other component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to update cart badge value (in the navbar component) everytime user click *Add to Cart* button (in the product-list component).

I have a cart button in navbar component (with a badge which have the value equal to the number of products being added in the cart)

navbar.html:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light" style="background-color: rgb(243, 208, 8);">
    <a class="navbar-brand store_title"> TeeRex Store </a>
    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto products" routerLink="/product-list" routerLinkActive="active_route"> Products </a>
    <p-button class="nav-link ms-auto cart_btn" [badge]="cart_length" routerLink="/shopping-cart" icon="pi pi-shopping-cart" [raised]="true"></p-button>
</nav> <br>
```

product-list.ts:

```
addToCart(product: any) {
    this._data.setShoppingCartList(product); // product is being added to the shopping list
}
```

I want to increment the badge value (in navbar) everytime user click this Add to Cart button. I just want to know how to update the value (cart_length) in the navbar component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Assuming that you have two unrelated components you can use a shared service to achieve this.

###### create a shared service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  private dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('initial data'); // Use behavioural subject to emit data
  data$ = this.dataSubject.asObservable();

  updateData(newData: string) {
    this.dataSubject.next(newData); // Emit new data to the data$
  }
}
```

###### In your component A :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-a',
  template: `
    <p>{{ data }}</p>
  `,
})
export class ComponentAComponent implements OnInit {
  data: string;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.data$.subscribe((newData) => {
      this.data = newData; // subscribe to the latest changes in OnInit
    });
  }
}
```

###### In component B :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-b',
  template: `
    <button (click)="updateData()">Update Data</button>
  `,
})
export class ComponentBComponent {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {} // dependency injection of service 

  updateData() {
    const newData = 'new data';
    this.dataService.updateData(newData);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want update or add, you can do like this

**Service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  data = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  addData(newData: object) {
     this.data.subscribe((items) => {
       this.data.next([...items,newData])
     })
  }

  updateData(newData: object) {
       this.data.subscribe((items) => {
          this.data.next(items.map((item) => item.id === newData.id ? newData: item))
       })
  }
}
```

**Component A**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-a',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let item of dataService.data | async">{{item.name}}</div>
  `,
})
export class ComponentAComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public dataService: DataService) {}
}
```

**Component B**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-b',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button (click)="addData(data)">Update Data</button>
      <button (click)="updateData(data)">Update Data</button>
   </div>
  `,
})
export class ComponentBComponent {
  data = {id: 'dataId', name: 'dataName'}

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {} // dependency injection of service 

  addData(data) {
    this.dataService.addData(data);
  }

  updateData(data) {
    this.dataService.updateData(data)
  }
}
```